# Trying to make a discord bot that creates a private channel for a member when they join

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot that creates a new channel that only admins and the member can see upon joining.

ChatGPT doesn't have updated knowledge on Discord 14.9.0 documentation so it's quite useless at assisting me.

I have very little experience in writing bots, or in Javascript in general.

My problem is: When a user joins, nothing happens. There is no error in the console either.

Here's my code for now:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXX';

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('guildMemberJoin', async (member) => {
  const guild = member.guild;
  const adminRole = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Admin'); // Replace 'Admin' with the name of the admin role on your server

  if (!adminRole) {
    console.error("Admin role not found. Make sure the role exists and the name matches.");
    return;
  }

  // Create a new text channel for the member.
  const channelName = `private-${member.user.username}`;
  const channel = await guild.channels.create({
    name: channelName,
    type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: guild.roles.everyone.id,
        deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
      },
      {
        id: member.id,
        allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGES'],
      },
      {
        id: adminRole.id,
        allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGES'],
      },
    ],
  });

  await channel.send(`Welcome, ${member.user}! This is your private channel.`);
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

If anyone could point out some faults in the code that would be very helpful. I believe it probably has some outdated code, causing it to not function as intended.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a private channel only the user and the bot can see in Discord.js v14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74562212/how-to-create-a-private-channel-only-the-user-and-the-bot-can-see-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the type of the channel using a string anymore, you have to use the new `ChannelType` enum. You can import it from the discord.js library, and once you've done that, creating a channel would look something like this:

```js
guild.channels.create({
    name: "hello",
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    parent: cat[0].ID,
    // your permission overwrites or other options here
});
```

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840981/5422841)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given is correct, but in your permission overwrites, it should be

```
permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone, // should be everyone like this
        deny: [
          PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel, // discord.js changed permission to enum
          PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages,
        ],
      },
    ],
```

as the code above shows that the permission isn't an array of permission now, you should use `PermissionFalgsBits` now, please refer to discord.js [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/CategoryCreateChannelOptions) for more information